# Append value from one list to another one using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list:

```
list_1 = ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04']
list_2 = ['2PM', '3PM', '4PM']
```

I want to merge the list do that the new list looks like this:

```
list = ['2000-01-01 2PM', 
        '2000-01-01 3PM', 
        '2000-01-01 4PM', 
        '2000-01-02 2PM', 
        '2000-01-02 3PM', 
        '2000-01-02 4PM',
        ................
        '2000-01-04 4PM']
```

Basically, for each value of `list_1`, I added every value of `list_2` separated by a space.

I did this using `Python`

```
for date in list_1:
  for hour in list_2:
     date +  " " + hour
```

How do I do it using `Pandas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MultiIndex` and `map`

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list_1, list_2]).map(' '.join).tolist()

Out[129]:
['2000-01-01 2PM',
 '2000-01-01 3PM',
 '2000-01-01 4PM',
 '2000-01-02 2PM',
 '2000-01-02 3PM',
 '2000-01-02 4PM',
 '2000-01-03 2PM',
 '2000-01-03 3PM',
 '2000-01-03 4PM',
 '2000-01-04 2PM',
 '2000-01-04 3PM',
 '2000-01-04 4PM']
```

---

Or use `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
list(map(' '.join, product(list_1, list_2)))

Out[134]:
['2000-01-01 2PM',
 '2000-01-01 3PM',
 '2000-01-01 4PM',
 '2000-01-02 2PM',
 '2000-01-02 3PM',
 '2000-01-02 4PM',
 '2000-01-03 2PM',
 '2000-01-03 3PM',
 '2000-01-03 4PM',
 '2000-01-04 2PM',
 '2000-01-04 3PM',
 '2000-01-04 4PM']
```

Answer (score 1):

An usage of `for loop`

```
[x + ' ' + y for x in list_1 for y in list_2]
['2000-01-01 2PM', '2000-01-01 3PM', '2000-01-01 4PM', '2000-01-02 2PM', '2000-01-02 3PM', '2000-01-02 4PM', '2000-01-03 2PM', '2000-01-03 3PM', '2000-01-03 4PM', '2000-01-04 2PM', '2000-01-04 3PM', '2000-01-04 4PM']
```